# Is there a way to reference bnd filename from a macro inside?

Tags: osgi, bnd, bndtools

I would like to use the filename of a sub-bundle bnd file as value without extension inside the file itself. like here ${filename_without_extension}
Is there a opportunity for that?

file: core.bnd

```
-includeresource: \
    @${filename_without_extension}.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`${thisfile}` gives you the file of the current bnd file. You can substitute the '.bnd' extension:

```
 fname = ${subst;${thisfile};\.bnd$;.jar}
 -includeresource: @${fname}
```